# Bug "Show Notes" in Preview Mac OS Catalina

Tags: mac, preview, printing, catalina

I have a problem with Preview. When I have to print a PDF with notes on it I click the button "Show notes" on the print window but nothing happens. How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Nobody can help?